# upload photo to facebook wall in android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am unable to upload photos directly to wall. 
Please see below code for the same. It posts the message to wall but photo is not uploaded and i do not get any error message.

```
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();                 
parameters.putByteArray("picture", imgData);
parameters.putString("message", "This is facebook post");
response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters,"POST");
```

If i use "**me/photos**" it uploads the photo to an album. 
Thanks 
MO

Answer (score 0):

Try this code its seems to work fine for me....

`Bitmap imagewall = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path));`

`ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();`

`imagewall.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);`

`byte[] bitmapdata = stream.toByteArray();`
`bundle.putByteArray("picture", bitmapdata);`

Comment: Nope it is not working. Same issue , message is getting posted but image does not appear.